# How to extract bank transaction infos with right regex condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, ecmascript-6

My purpose is to read a bank document which contains all my transactions of the month.
Today, I manually enter all my transactions in an excel.
I would like to automatize it.
Thus, this afternoon, I was trying to read the pdf and extract the text.

For that, I used pdf-parse library.
On the document, the transactions lines look like :

```
31-12-2019 Forfait 01-01-2019 - 31-12-2019 -29,00 // (loose money)  
31-12-2019 Forfait 01-01-2019 - 31-12-2019 50,00 // (win money)
31-12-2019 Mercedes -500,00 // (loose money) 
31-12-2019 Client 10 700,00 // (win money)
```

But with the pdf reader, I receive :

```
31-12-2019Forfait 01-01-2019 - 31-12-2019-29,00
31-12-2019Forfait 01-01-2019 - 31-12-201950,00
31-12-2019Mercedes-500,00
31-12-2019Client10 700,00
```

My purpose is to extract : **date - text - amount.**

```
const transactions = data.text.split('\n').filter(val => { 
// regex matching the transaction line of my pdf
});
```

I would like to extract this with some regex.
But I can't find the right way. For loose of money, we could separate it easily.
However, when the transaction is positive, it becomes difficult to detect the right amount, example :

```
31-12-2019Forfait 01-01-2019 - 31-12-201950,00 
// expected {  date:31-12-2019  text: Forfait 01-01-2019 - 31-12-2019  amount: 50,00 }  
31-12-2019Client10 700,00
// expected { date:31-12-2019 text: Client amount: 10 700,00 }
```

I tried :

```
(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})([a-zA-Z!@#%$&'()\-\`." ]+)([-?\d ]*,[\d]+)
```

But does not cover every case I found.
Typically, when in the description, you have number at the end.
other example :

```
31-12-2019Comptoir1750,00
// expected 31-12-2019 Comptoir17 50,00
```

Do you have any idea ?

thanks a lot,

Comment: Does your bank offer your transactions in any other format than PDF? A lot of banks also offer these as CSV. However JSON, XML and other formats will be a lot easier to parse than a PDF. Or is there a reason you must use PDF specifically?

Comment: How can you tell these 2 apart? `Comptoir17` and `50,00`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird indeed, that's exactly my problem here. But I found today an another pdf reader which gives me a better separation of the text data in an array. And I can apply a specific pattern on this array result.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Good question, thoses documents are the officiel ones. I should connect to my online bank dashboard to see if there are another doc type. :p

Comment: If there are no patterns that one can name in order to distinguish all possible cases, then there is also no way of putting it into code, especially with `Comptoir 1750,00` which could be anything like `Comptoir 1 750,00` or `Comptoir 17 50,00`. But `17-12-19 to 22-12-1950,00` has a pattern which I'd resolve to `17-12-19 to 22-12-19 50,00` due to the repeating date pattern of `DD-MM-YY`. As for now, a more clean approach was focusing again on retrieving entirely reliable input data (a process that does not destroy the semantics of the original document unlike the current pdf-reader based one).

Answer (score 1):

A regex with [named capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) like ... [`(/^\s*(?<date>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\s*(?<text>[^\s-]+(?:(?:[\s-]*\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})+)?)\s*(?<amount>-*\d+,\d+)/gm)`](https://regex101.com/r/7TdghZ/1) ... enables an approach based on ... `data.text.`[`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#Regexp.exec_and_matchAll) ...

```js
const data = { text: `31-12-2019Forfait 01-01-2019 - 31-12-2019-29,00
31-12-2019Forfait 01-01-2019 - 31-12-201950,00
31-12-2019Mercedes-500,00
31-12-2019Client10 700,00
31-12-2019Comptoir17 50,00` };

// see: [https://regex101.com/r/7TdghZ/1]

// const regXDataCaptures = (/^(?<date>[\d-]+)\s*(?<text>[^\s-]+(?:(?:[\s-]*\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})+)?)\s*(?<amount>-*\d+,\d+)/gm);

const regXDataCaptures = (/^\s*(?<date>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\s*(?<text>[^\s-]+(?:(?:[\s-]*\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})+)?)\s*(?<amount>-*\d+,\d+)/gm);

const dataList = [
  ...data.text.matchAll(regXDataCaptures)
].map(({ groups }) => ({ ...groups }));

console.log('dataList :', dataList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

In order to avoid too complicated expressions (in terms of comprehension and maintenance) and also to be less vulnerable to edge cases I personally prefer splitting such processes into sub tasks that can handle each one problem at a time more reliable.

A solution that follows such an approach then might use two regular expressions like ... [`(/^\s*(?<date>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/)`](https://regex101.com/r/Oj11JY/1/) and [`(/(?:(?:[\s-]*\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})+)?\s*(?<amount>-*\d+,\d+)\s*$/)`](https://regex101.com/r/LTgHd2/1/) ... and might look similar to the next provided one ...

```js
const data = { text: `31-12-2019Forfait 01-01-2019 - 31-12-2019-29,00
31-12-2019Forfait 01-01-2019 - 31-12-201950,00
31-12-2019Mercedes-500,00
31-12-2019 Client 10 700,00
31-12-2019Comptoir 17-50,00` };

// see: [https://regex101.com/r/Oj11JY/1/]
const regXCaptureDate = (/^\s*(?<date>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/);

// see: [https://regex101.com/r/LTgHd2/1/]
const regXCaptureAmount = (/(?:(?:[\s-]*\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})+)?\s*(?<amount>-*\d+,\d+)\s*$/);


function isNonEmptyStringValue(value) {
  return ((typeof value === 'string') && (value !== ''));
}

function createAndCollectRecord(list, rawRecordItem) {
  const record = {
    ...(regXCaptureDate.exec(rawRecordItem) || {}).groups,
    ...(regXCaptureAmount.exec(rawRecordItem) || {}).groups,
    text: rawRecordItem
      .replace(regXCaptureDate, '')
      .replace(regXCaptureAmount, '')
      .trim()
  };
  if (
    ['date', 'amount', 'text']
      .every(key => isNonEmptyStringValue(record[key]))
  ) {
    list.push(record);
  }
  return list;
}


const dataList = data.text
  .split(/\n/)
  .reduce(createAndCollectRecord, []);

console.log('dataList :', dataList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your feedback. My issue was with this kind of line : 31-12-2019Comptoir 1750,00. 
I can't differentiate the price : is it 1750,00 or 50,00 or 750,00 ? 
Same thing is I receive : 31-12-2019Comptoir from 17-12-19 to 22-12-1950,00.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it covers all the cases you provided. Although I caution this approach since it is fragile and can break easily with cases you haven't encountered in your data yet.

https://regex101.com/r/tMbNPZ/1

```
^(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{2,4})(([\w\d]+\s?\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}]?\s\-\s\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{4})|([\w]+))(([\d\,]+)|(\s[\d\,]+)|(\-[\d\,]+))
```

Comment: Hey, I may have expressed myself badly. I meaned I already extract thoses lines. 
The problem is specifically when we have : 
31-12-2019Comptoir 1750,00. I can't differentiate the price : is it 1750,00 or 50,00 or 750,00 ?
Same thing if I receive : 31-12-2019Comptoir from 17-12-19 to 22-12-1950,00